# Can I connect my mern stack application to an OPC UA server

Tags: reactjs, mern, opc-ua, opc, node-opcua

I have my masters project due in a month and my professor has now asked me to connect what I've made using the MERN stack to an OPC UA simulation environment.

Is this even possible? I'm looking around online and can't find much, if anyone can point me in the right direction and provide helpful resources I'd be very grateful

Many thanks

Comment: I guess you only need to use an existing OPC UA NodeJS Client and connect to an OPC UA Server ?